# If there is no command-line argument, read stdin Python

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, command-line-arguments, stdin

So I have a text file called ids that looks like this:

```
15 James
13 Leon
1 Steve
5 Brian
```

And my Python program (id.py) is supposed to read the file name as a command-line argument, put everything in a dictionary where the IDs are the keys, and print the output sorted numerically by IDs. This is the expected output:

```
1 Steve
5 Brian
13 Leon
15 James
```

I got it working for this part (calling on terminal `python id.py ids`). However, now I am supposed to check if there is no arguments, it will read `stdin` (for example, `python id.py < ids`), and eventually print out the same expected output. However, it crashes right here. This is my program:

```
entries = {}

file;

if (len(sys.argv) == 1):
      file = sys.stdin
else:
      file = sys.argv[-1] # command-line argument

with open (file, "r") as inputFile:
   for line in inputFile: # loop through every line
      list = line.split(" ", 1) # split between spaces and store into a list

      name = list.pop(1) # extract name and remove from list
      name = name.strip("\n") # remove the \n
      key = list[0] # extract id 

      entries[int(key)] = name # store keys as int and name in dictionary

   for e in sorted(entries): # numerically sort dictionary and print 
      print "%d %s" % (e, entries[e])
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? I suspect `sys.stdin` cannot be opened like a regular file.

Answer (score 4):

`sys.stdin` is an already-open (for reading) file. Not a file name:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin
<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0x7f817e63b0c0>
```

So you can use it already with the file object api.

You could try something like this:

```
if (len(sys.argv) == 1):
    fobj = sys.stdin
else:
    fobj = open(sys.argv[-1], 'r') # command-line argument

# ... use file object
```

Comment: So how do I implement my if-else so I don't have to put the whole with statement inside each if and else block? The else block can have the exact same code beneath it, but the if block only needs: for line in sys.stdin and the rest